# Is it possible to have a default parameter for a mysql stored procedure?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, default-value

I have googled this and keep coming up with "No it is not possible" but these posts were dated 2005-2007 so I'm wondering if this has been changed. A code example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `blah`
(
  myDefaultParam int = 0 -- This breaks the code for some reason
)
BEGIN
  -- Do something here
END
```

One of the solutions has been to pass null and then check for null and set the variable. I don't want to do that and I shouldn't have to. If this is true then MySql devs need to wake up because there is so much more I could do with MSSQL.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652241/writing-optional-parameters-within-stored-procedures-in-mysql

Comment: does mariaDB has this same problem?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's still not possible.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Like checking if the parameter is null then give it a default value?

Comment: @papaiatis Yes you can just add an if statement, see my other post below.

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer when below here @Dive50 has a useful workaround, which I'm about to implement because I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: That's why I hate MySQL. Such a basic thing still not there

Comment: It's not possible to use the syntax suggested but passing NULL and then using IFNULL is perfectly possible and achieves exactly the same thing.

Comment: does mariaDB has this same problem?

Comment: So, what about 14 years later?

Answer (score 59):

We worked around this limitation by adding a simple IF statement in the stored procedure. Practically we pass an empty string whenever we want to save the default value in the DB.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `myProc`(IN myVarParam VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
  IF myVarParam = '' THEN SET myVarParam = 'default-value'; END IF;

  ...your code here...
END
```

Comment: Why not use `null` instead?

Comment: this shows how much love you can give to mysql, meanwhile in sql you can simply put " param_name int(11) = NULL" ... thank you Oracle

Answer (score 39):

```
SET myParam = IFNULL(myParam, 0);
```

Explanation: `IFNULL(expression_1, expression_2)`

The `IFNULL` function returns `expression_1` if `expression_1` is not `NULL`; otherwise it returns `expression_2`. The `IFNULL` function returns a string or a numeric based on the context where it is used.

Comment: this is more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 12):

If you look into [CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/create-procedure.html) for latest MySQL version you'll see that procedure parameter can only contain IN/OUT/INOUT specifier, parameter name and type.

So, default values are still unavailable in latest MySQL version.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support `DEFAULT` parameter values, so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `blah`
(
  myDefaultParam int DEFAULT 0
)
BEGIN
  -- Do something here
END
```

returns the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'DEFAULT 0) BEGIN END' at line 3
```

To work around this limitation, simply create additional procedures that assign default values to the original procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS blah//
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS blah2//
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS blah1//
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS blah0//

CREATE PROCEDURE blah(param1 INT UNSIGNED, param2 INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
    SELECT param1, param2;
END;
//

CREATE PROCEDURE blah2(param1 INT UNSIGNED, param2 INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
    CALL blah(param1, param2);
END;
//

CREATE PROCEDURE blah1(param1 INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
    CALL blah2(param1, 3);
END;
//

CREATE PROCEDURE blah0()
BEGIN
    CALL blah1(4);
END;
//
```

Then, running this:

```
CALL blah(1, 1);
CALL blah2(2, 2);
CALL blah1(3);
CALL blah0();
```

will return:

```
+--------+--------+
| param1 | param2 |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+--------+--------+
| param1 | param2 |
+--------+--------+
|      2 |      2 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+--------+--------+
| param1 | param2 |
+--------+--------+
|      3 |      3 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

+--------+--------+
| param1 | param2 |
+--------+--------+
|      4 |      3 |
+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then, if you make sure to only use the `blah2()`, `blah1()` and `blah0()` procedures, your code will not need to be immediately updated, when you add a third parameter to the `blah()` procedure.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported in MySQL stored routine syntax.

Feel free to submit a feature request at [bugs.mysql.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/how-to-report.php).

Comment: Posting this from the other question I asked:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975