# Adding parameters with NULL default value for MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I add parameters with NULL default value for MySQL stored procedure?

Comment: 'case when` could be used. Post what you have tried please.

Comment: I tried to add it but, it does not work, thanx

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652241/writing-optional-parameters-within-stored-procedures-in-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a default parameter for a mysql stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982798/is-it-possible-to-have-a-default-parameter-for-a-mysql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982824/1319179) MySQL does not support true 'default parameters' in functions or stored procedures.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404731/1319179) on the same page provides a solution that may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Any query with variable and 'case`:-

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @NullValue:=Null;  
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Sum(myField) Is Null 
    THEN @NullValue ELSE Sum(myField)
    END AS Total 
    FROM table_name; 
END
;
```