# Flexible Update Stored Procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am looking for a flexible update stored procedure. I made this one.
When i call this CALL spUpdatePage(1,'a','b','c''d') it works fine.

Do i have to pass always in this example 5 params?

Can i also do this

```
CALL spUpdatePage(1,'a','c')
```

and that the stored procedure knows that i only want to update the columns name and description?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spUpdatePage`(
IN `pKey` INT(4), 
IN `name` VARCHAR(255), 
IN `title` VARCHAR(255), 
IN `description` VARCHAR(255), 
IN `keywords` VARCHAR(255))
UPDATE
    pages
SET
    name = COALESCE(name, name),
    title = COALESCE(title, title),
    description = COALESCE(description, description),
    keywords = COALESCE(keywords, keywords)
WHERE
    id = pKey
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a default parameter for a mysql stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982798/is-it-possible-to-have-a-default-parameter-for-a-mysql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to pass always in this example 5 params?
>
> Can I also do this?
>
> ```
> CALL spUpdatePage(1,'a','c')
> ```

For your posted stored procedure, you must pass all 5 parameters. No, you can't just pass `name` and `description` (to your posted stored procedure). However, you could write a stored procedure that only updates `name` and `description`. Something like,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spUpdatePageNameTitle`(
  IN `pKey` INT(4), 
  IN `name` VARCHAR(255), 
  IN `title` VARCHAR(255))
UPDATE
  pages
SET
  name = COALESCE(name, name),
  title = COALESCE(title, title)
WHERE
  id = pKey
```

Comment: Stupid question of me. Doesnt work. So Stored Procedure isnt flexible... So you have to post always all params... Thnx!

Comment: @Bas See also [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/982824/2970947).