# sql stored proc "Default Parameter Values"

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, toad

I'm trying to set "Default Parameter Values" in stored proc. 
i know the syntax TYPE 1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name @param nvarchar(30) = NULL, @param1 nvarchar(60) = NULL
```

My TOAD 7.3 using mysql 5.1.35 is giving a syntax of TYPE 2: when I create new Procedure

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE name (param_name param_type)
for e.g: create procedure test (IN name varchar(50))
```

but i can't find the right syntax to set 'IN' values

```
create procedure test (in name varchar(50) = null)
```

is throwing syntax error.

please tell me the right syntax to set default parameters in type 2.
I've searched a lot in and out of SO for this, no luck :\

Comment: As i found from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982798/is-it-possible-to-have-a-default-parameter-for-a-mysql-stored-procedure) **It's still not possible.** You can add your default parameter in Where clause something like this WHERE id = @id or id = "some default value"

Comment: This is the mysql 5.1 create stored procedure documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html It says nothing about default declaration :/

Comment: @bish yeah, I've been through that and many docs, I can't find anything usefull for my prob. it sucks. older versions could do it.   
N.Molderf thanks , that assures me I can't get it done in 5.1. 
so should I use an older version using TYPE1(in my ques) syntax? which version would be the best for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't **explicitly** do that, but you could simulate it, in some cases. I just now had a case of that, where the parameter I wanted a default value to, was being checked in an IF statement. Here's how I did it:

[image: screenshot of the solution]

In the body of my `condAddNewLineTo`, I had `if` statement. Since my function was to conditionally return things, I simply put my default behavior **outside** of those if-statements. Like this:

```
IF varToCheck = <nonDefaultValue> THEN
    #some lines of code to execute
    RETURN <value>;
END IF;
# default behavior here
RETURN <defaultValue>;
```

Alternately, if not writing stored function that returns stuff, you could do something like:

```
IF varToCheck = <nonDefaultValue> THEN
    # some lines of code to execute
ELSE 
    # some default code
END IF;
```

Hope this helps!