# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql

Define procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Reporting(IN tablename VARCHAR(20))
proc_label:BEGIN
     IF tablename IS NULL THEN
            SELECT 'Null detect';
          LEAVE proc_label;
     END IF;

     SELECT 'after';
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Call Procedure:

```
CALL SP_Reporting();
```

Error :

> ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE
>   cds.SP_Reporting ; expected 1, got 0

How pass var by default  like `SP_Reporting(IN tablename = 'default value' VARCHAR(20))`

Comment: Pehaps CALL SP_Reporting(null); ?

Comment: duplicate: [Writing optional parameters within stored procedures in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652241/writing-optional-parameters-within-stored-procedures-in-mysql). Also: [Is it possible to have a default parameter for a mysql stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982798/is-it-possible-to-have-a-default-parameter-for-a-mysql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3):

When you are making your stored procedure, you can assign a value to your input, so there is no need to pass parameters while you are calling the proc.

We usually assign `NULL` and for making parameters optional, we use this method.

```
tablename VARCHAR(20) = NULL
```

Your complete script:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Reporting(IN tablename VARCHAR(20) = NULL)
proc_label:BEGIN
     IF tablename IS NULL THEN
            SELECT 'Null detect';
          LEAVE proc_label;
     END IF;

     SELECT 'after';
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**

MySQL is not accepting optional parameters. So one way is to pass `NULL` value in your stored procedure and check it with `IF` statement inside your proc.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Reporting(IN tablename VARCHAR(20))
proc_label:BEGIN
     IF tablename IS NULL THEN
            -- Do something;
     ELSE
            -- Do something else;
     END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the table name in the procedure call statement like:

CALL SP_Reporting(table_name);

you can't pass default in call statement.
You can assign default value before calling the procedure.
or use OUT instead of IN as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you miss the parameter :tablename 
you should like this : 
call SP_Reporting('any varchar')
or 
call SP_Reporting(null)